# Security issue about using bbcode parser vs antiXSS library

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, parsing, bbcode, antixsslibrary

In my application, I have rich textbox, and I  wonder what is safer to use:

- A bbcode rich textbox with bbcode parser,

or

- A rich textbox with html encoded tags, and validation with Microsoft anti-XSS sanitizer

I think that first approach is a bit harder to implement, because I would need to write a custom bbcode validator/sanitizer.

So, which method would you use, and why?

Comment: At least with the latest version (4.2.1), you'll find out that HTML sanitization with MS AntiXSS Library is pretty much useless (http://wpl.codeplex.com/workitem/17246).

Comment: So, how can i secure my rich textbox inputs, what is the best way of doing that?